# Uncaught TypeError: i.dateFormat is not a function at jquery.datetimepicker.min.js:2 (anonymous)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to implement date and time picker, I am  getting the Uncaught TypeError: i.dateFormat is not a function at jquery.datetimepicker.min.js:2 on console.The below is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
 <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

I am following the below link:

http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/datetimepicker#field_options

Comment: Try to use the non minified version of the script

Comment: tried  but same error

Comment: Do these files exist on your server in the correct location? I would remove the `/` from the start of the `src`. Wrong relative path.

Comment: yes files are exist and giving above exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change: `<script src="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>`
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfhmr0oq/)